# jQuery event propagation does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to propagate events with jQuery using the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#main').click(function(e){
var el = e.target.nodeName;
var $jObj = $(el);//jQuery object
$jObj.css('color','green');
});
});
```

This is the simple html code:

```
<div id="main">
<p>Test one</p>
<p>Test two</p>
<p>Test three</p>
</div>
```

Now, If I click on one of the p elements not only the selected **p** changes the color to green, but all **p**. I cannot understand the resaon. According to the jQuery script above only the selected `<p>` should change the colour.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the jQuery script above only the selected `p`

I doubt that. You are selecting **all** `p` elements:

```
var el = e.target.nodeName; // el = "P"
var $jObj = $(el);//jQuery object // equiv to $("p")
```

`e.target.nodeName` is the value `"P"` which you then use as selector, and `$("P")` selects *all* `p` elements.

To only select the event target, pass the DOM element itself to jQuery:

```
$(e.target)
```

Relevant documentation: [`jQuery(element)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element), [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#main').click(function(e){
var $jObj = $(e.target);//jQuery object
$jObj.css('color','green');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<p>Test one</p>
<p>Test two</p>
<p>Test three</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your answer. Now the script is workink properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#main > p').click(function(e){
         $(this).css('color','green');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main').find('p').on('click', function(){
      $(this).css('color','green');    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<p>Test one</p>
<p>Test two</p>
<p>Test three</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to event delegate using `on` of `JQUERY`, when you click on `p` element, assign `this` to a variable and then use it as selector object before apply css

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
   $('#main').on('click','p',function(e)
   {
    var el = this;
    var $jObj = $(el);//jQuery object, see here carefully
    $jObj.css('color','green');
   });
 });
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/upq9k3e5/)